# Is possible to add post-formats to custom-post-type?

Tags: custom-post-types, post-formats

I was wondering if **there is some way to put together the custom-post-types and post-formats** so I can code a new post type and offer some variations as post-formats.

I'm involved in a **company directory conceptualization** and we have to mix different kind of company. While almost all of this types share the same data fields, there are two specific kind of companies - hotels & bistros - which has especific requirements (custom taxonomies and some data fields).

In your opinion, **which is the best approach**?

- Use three custom-post-type: 'company', 'bistro' & 'hotel'.
- Use one custom-post-type w/ post-formats.
- Use only one custom-post-type and use conditional logic to add or not specific data-models.

Thanks in advance!!!

*Xavier*

Comment: possible duplicate of [Custom Post Formats](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28015/custom-post-formats)

Answer (score 2):

For those coming here because of the title of the question:

If you have a look at [Post Formats at the Codex](http://codex.wordpress.org/Post_Formats) you'll see that

> [...] New formats cannot be introduced by themes or even plugins. [...]

Which kills you're option 2.

Also have a look at this: [Custom Post Formats](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/28015/custom-post-formats?rq=1)

For your apparent actual question:
It really depends on how much they differ. But if they have different taxonomies and different data fields I'd say have separate post types.

Comment: Aught! Thanks @kraftner, you add some light. Definitely I'll use three custom-post-type.